# jquery input selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, input, selector

```
var inputvalue = $(this).attr('value')
             $('input[value=inputvalue] + label').css({
                    '-webkit-transition': 'opacity 0.4s linear',
                    'opacity': '0'
                });
```

But it does not work. As expected value=inputvalue does not get that variable but looks for that name. How can i do this?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Have you considered using `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).attr('value')`? Oh, and the attribute-equals selector requires the values to be quoted. 'Quotes are mandatory.' Reference: [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Can you post your markup? It will help us understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some string concatenation here.

```
var inputvalue = $(this).val();
$('input[value="' + inputvalue + '"] + label').css({
  '-webkit-transition': 'opacity 0.4s linear',
  'opacity': '0'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/JMShX/1/)

HTML:

```
<label for="myinput">Label for input</label>
<input id="myinput" />
<button>check</button>
<br />
```

JS:

```
$.expr[':'].value = function(obj, index, meta, stack){

    if (meta[3] == $(obj).val())
        return true;    

    return false;
};

$.fn.labelInput = function() {

    if (this && $(this).attr('id'))
        return $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]');

    return null;
}

$('button').bind('click', function(event) {

   var 
       inputvalue = $('input').val(),
       cssOpcions = {
          '-webkit-transition': 'opacity 0.4s linear',
          'opacity': '0'
        };

    $('input:value(' + inputvalue + ')')
        .css(cssOpcions)
        .labelInput().css(cssOptions);

});
```